# Python tkinter next page

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to move from one page to another. I don't know if page [i] is a variable, but this code should work in my logic. Can you help me where I'm making a mistake?

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
def page1():
    page2text.pack_forget()
    page3text.pack_forget()
    page1text.pack()

def page2():
    page1text.pack_forget()
    page2text.pack()
    page3text.pack_forget()

def page3():
    page1text.pack_forget()
    page2text.pack_forget()
    page3text.pack()
pagelist="123"
i=iter(pagelist)
page="page"
page1btn = tkinter.Button(window, text="Next", command=page+next(i))
page2btn = tkinter.Button(window, text="Exit", command=quit)

page1text = tkinter.Label(window, text="This is page 1")
page2text = tkinter.Label(window, text="This is page 2")
page3text = tkinter.Label(window, text="This is page 3")

page1btn.pack()
page2btn.pack()
page1text.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: whats your current errors?

Comment: next button does not work. i don't know the error

Comment: ***"next button does not work"***: This is invalid: `command=page+next(i)`, you can't build a `command=...` from `str`.

Comment: `command=` need function name without `()` and arguments - it is called "callback" - so it can later use `()` to run it. Using string "page" you can't create function. Use directly name `page1` or keep functions in dictionary and then you can use string to get function - `func["page1"] = page1` and `command=func["page1"]`.

Comment: BTW: to create 3 buttons you need `for`-loop. Using only `next()` you can't create 3 buttons.

Comment: there are functions to convert string to function or variable but prefered is to use dictionary for this. Keep functions in dictionary `func = {"page1":page1, "page2":page2, "page3":page3}` and then you can get function from dictionary `func["page1"]` and use `()` to run it `func["page1"]()`

Comment: BTW: you can also use list and dictionary to keep buttons and labels so later you can use the same string to show/hide them - `labels["1"].pack_forget()` `buttons["1"].pack()`

Comment: I have one more question. I want to list the physical disks. I'm doing os.system ("parted -l") but return 0. os.system ("parted -l> disk.lst"). I feel like I'm on the wrong track.

Comment: `os.system()` runs function which display text directly on screen but it returns exit code from this function - `0` means `'no error'`. To get displayed text you would need functions from module [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) - ie. [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

Comment: thanks. Can you suggest pdf or book or website please?I'm too late to learn python.

Comment: I uses only Google to search information, tutorials, examples. Usually modules have pages with documentation which has some examples .

Comment: `tkinter` has old and incomplete [documentation on effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm)  but it is still very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dictinary to keep functions and even buttons and labels and then you can use string to access them.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def page1():
    labels["1"].pack()
    labels["2"].pack_forget()
    labels["3"].pack_forget()

def page2():
    labels["1"].pack_forget()
    labels["2"].pack()
    labels["3"].pack_forget()

def page3():
    labels["1"].pack_forget()
    labels["2"].pack_forget()
    labels["3"].pack()

# --- main ---

window = tk.Tk()

func = {
    "1": page1,
    "2": page2,
    "3": page3,
}

buttons = {
    "1": tk.Button(window, text="Page 1", command=func["1"]),
    "2": tk.Button(window, text="Page 2", command=func["2"]),
    "3": tk.Button(window, text="Page 3", command=func["3"]),
}

labels = {
    "1": tk.Label(window, text="This is page 1"),
    "2": tk.Label(window, text="This is page 2"),
    "3": tk.Label(window, text="This is page 3"),
}    

buttons["1"].pack()
buttons["2"].pack()
buttons["3"].pack()

labels["1"].pack()

window.mainloop()
```

You can even use `for`-loop for this

```
buttons = {}
labels = {}

for x in range(1, 4):
    buttons[str(x)] = tk.Button(window, text="Page "+str(x), command=func[str(x)])
    labels[str(x)] = tk.Label(window, text="This is page "+str(x))
```

---

**EDIT:** code which shows only one button on page

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def page1():
    buttons["1"].pack_forget()    
    buttons["2"].pack()
    buttons["3"].pack_forget()

    labels["1"].pack()
    labels["2"].pack_forget()
    labels["3"].pack_forget()

def page2():
    buttons["1"].pack_forget()    
    buttons["2"].pack_forget()
    buttons["3"].pack()

    labels["1"].pack_forget()
    labels["2"].pack()
    labels["3"].pack_forget()

def page3():
    buttons["1"].pack()    
    buttons["2"].pack_forget()
    buttons["3"].pack_forget()

    labels["1"].pack_forget()
    labels["2"].pack_forget()
    labels["3"].pack()

# --- main ---

window = tk.Tk()

func = {
    "1": page1,
    "2": page2,
    "3": page3,
}

buttons = {
    "1": tk.Button(window, text="Next (Page 1)", command=func["1"]),
    "2": tk.Button(window, text="Next (Page 2)", command=func["2"]),
    "3": tk.Button(window, text="Next (Page 3)", command=func["3"]),
}

labels = {
    "1": tk.Label(window, text="This is page 1"),
    "2": tk.Label(window, text="This is page 2"),
    "3": tk.Label(window, text="This is page 3"),
}    

buttons["2"].pack()
labels["1"].pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks but that's not what I want. want to do the next in the previous form. 2 buttons. It'il be 3 pages. default page next next next etc. Think like setup.

Comment: you wanted to assign function to buttons and this solutions show it :)

Comment: better use `Frame` to group elements and then you can show and hide `Frame` instead of showing and hiding every element separatelly. In many questions you can even see example with class `Page` which use Frames for this - but class `Page` is not standard element. It was created in some question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: if you show at start only first button and use `button[..].pack()` in functions then you get what you want.

Comment: BTW in this simple example you could even create only one button and one label and later change text on label and button and assign different function to button. `label["text"] = "new text"`, `button["text"] = "new text"`, `button["command"]  = new_function`.